Per-user or per-project gem cache path
Trying to pack my Ruby app, I get a lot of errors like this:
Bundler::PermissionError There was an error while trying to write
to `/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/cache/nio4r-2.7.1.gem`. It is
likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.

...which is nothing surprising, I myself removed the permissions from my user account. Maybe the ruby development thinks it differently, but honestly I find the idea of an all-user writable gem cache path hilarious.
How can I use my own gem cache path for everything? (Including bundle package, so a bundle install --local is not okay). Note, this question is asking some different one (OP wants to use a local dir as gem cache, I want to use the system gem directory in another place, anyways no answers written there works for me, I still get these errors).
What I would like the most: that would be some similar as the project-local node_modules directory is doing in the node.js world. So, all dependencies are downloaded into the local project directory, and nothing root permission is needed to install any of them.

Quite surprisingly, the solution was these:

BUNDLE_CACHE_PATH environment variable is where bundle will keep its cache.
Also GEM_HOME is needed to determine where gem will keep its separate cache (in another format).
While bundling the app, bundler will call gem, but these have independent cache directories, only the ruby devs know, why.
Instead bundle install, a prefered way is to use bundle package. That will package the files into BUNDLE_CACHE_PATH, instead of a local system-wide, normally readonly directory.

The relation of "gem" and "bundle" is still not clear. What is clear:
The ordinary package manager (like mvn in Java or npm in node.js) is done in Ruby with 3 tools:

Gem plays with induvidual Gems (gem is a ruby package)
Bundle plays if there is a navigation needed in the Gem dependency graphs
Rake is a tool like GNU Make (or "npm run" or "maven-exec-plugin"). So that is for recipe-based script execution.

The feature conflict between Gem and Bundle is clearly a disadvantage of the whole Ruby world, these all should be the same (or they should have very clearly differentiated and well documented responsibilities).

If a better answer appears, that will get the pipe and not mine.
